# How to send Sql query output as mail using talend?

Tags: sql-server, talend

I'm new to talend and wanted to execute an job which would send my Sql query output as mail to the recipients .The query needs to be run on daily basis and the output should be attached to mail.It'd be great if anyone can help me with components and connection.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I have connected various components  as-->
 tftpconnection>tftpget>tinputexcel>tmap>tdboutput>tdbsp.
 I just require the output.How should we proceed ahead?
 Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so you can use tmssqlinput(tdbinput) and send the output to the excel file using texceloutput component. Later use tsendemail and give the excel path in the attachment section.. Thats it you will be all set